# Publishing an InfoPath Form - where has it gone

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I've created and published an InfoPath 2013 form to SharePoint Online - horay you cry, but I don't know where it is...??

The form properties points me to the InfoPath Library I created but when I click the link the library is empty. Any ideas why I cant see the newly published form I created?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just need to press the new document button and I get my form - something so simple can be so obscured....